# Never go in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I made a simple rest service and I wanted to add a simple security on the api.
So I created an WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter :

```
package org.test.subscription.webservice.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

                auth
                        .inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("test1").password("test1").roles("superAdminRole").and()
                        .withUser("test2").password("test2").roles("superAdminRole");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                        http.httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("webserviceReadRole").and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }
}
```

And this is my main runner:

```
package org.test.subscription.webservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

}
```

But when I call something inside my API,I'm not authenticate at all, and I get my "hello world" response. So he never check my role. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example should work as you expect it (tested in boot 1.5.7 and also 2.0.0 M3). So I would recommend that you try the following. First verify some trivial things:

1. That you do not have anything that disables security checks in your `application.properties` or the corresponding yaml (e.g. something like `security.ignored` and Co.).
2. That you do not have another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in your application.
3. That your classes are scanned correctly by Spring.
4. That you do not have some strange cookies in the browser. E.g. try the same request by starting the browser in private mode or use curl or something similar.

If it still does not work enable the Spring Security debugger for a deeper insight on what is going on under the hood and why you see unexpected behavior. This may be achieved in the following way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
```

This will hint Spring to print lots of extra details which will help you find out what is wrong. In your setup you should see something like the following in the logs when you issue an request.

First, the request itself with the proper headers. Example with the most important parts:

```
Request received for GET '/path/to/your/api':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@58a4ad1c

authorization: Basic dGVzdDE6dGVzdDE=
cookie: JSESSIONID=9E4EBB889BB178E05446104EF2787C2F
```

Then you will see the filter chain managed by the `FilterChainProxy` and matched with your request (note that there might be other filter chains depending on the setup of your app - the log shows the matched chain which may not be the one that you expect):

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Then lots of `DEBUG` messages will follow in the log. Please pay special attention to the messages created around the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`:

```
2017-10-07 14:42:21.644 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pat/to/your/api at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2017-10-07 14:42:21.645 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'test1'
2017-10-07 14:42:21.645 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2017-10-07 14:42:21.647 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8fc16c08: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6924ddf: Username: test1; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_superAdminRole; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9E4EBB889BB178E05446104EF2787C2F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_superAdminRole
2
```

And also to the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which should output the successful authorization message:

```
2017-10-07 14:42:21.649 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8fc16c08: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6924ddf: Username: test1; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_superAdminRole; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9E4EBB889BB178E05446104EF2787C2F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_superAdminRole
2017-10-07 14:42:21.649 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1ca8b2d, returned: 1
2017-10-07 14:42:21.649 DEBUG 56071 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
```

Armed with all these details approach SO further :-)

Comment: Now it's working, thank you! I don't know really the source of the issue, I guess something link with a cache-cookie (I had to restart my computer).

Comment: I figure out the source of the issue: postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) has a cache system.